# Проверка наличия строк в файле

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. 
Подскажите пожалуйста.
Имеется скрипт на PHP который при запуске парсит 10 ссылок на картинки со стены одной группы в ВК и записывает их в файл на фтп.

Мне нужно сделать условие с проверкой, что бы скрипт спарсивал ссылку, заходил в файл и проверял есть ли там уже такая, если есть - то пропустить, если нет - записать к остальным.

Заранее благодарен

Comment: это проверка по всем строкам для каждой ссылки, вполне таки затратная процедура, если в файле будет немало строк

Comment: Может быть у вас будет другая идея как это можно реализовать? Буду благодарен

Comment: Идеи нет, но как реализовать вышеописанное уже пишу в ответ

Comment: А сколько ожидаетья картинок например за месяц? Какая версия PHP на сервере? Почему не с базой данных?

Comment: Конечно, было бы правильней делать все через бд, но для начала мне вполне хватит файла. Картинок ожидается не много, до 100 шт

Comment: @ВладимирВ. использовать БД, как подсказал товарищ выше - хорошая идея. Проще сразу подумать о расширяемости вашего парсера и сделать все с помощью БД, даже если сейчас вы думаете что этого делать не придется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Версия с генераторами (PHP 5.5 +).

```
<?php
// Читаем файл построчно.
function getLines($file) {
    $f = fopen($file, 'r');
    try {
        while ($line = fgets($f)) {
            yield $line;
        }
    } finally {
        fclose($f);
    }
}

$file = "links.txt";
$link = "http://example.com/image2.png";
$exists = false;

// Проверяем ссылку.
foreach (getLines($file) as $line) {
    $exists = $exists || trim($line) === $link;
}

if (!$exists) {
    file_put_contents ($file, $link . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

**Полный ответ :**

```
<?php

function getLines($file) {
    $f = fopen($file, 'r');
    try {
        while ($line = fgets($f)) {
            yield $line;
        }
    } finally {
        fclose($f);
    }
}

$url = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?domain=*NAME_OF_GROUP*&");
$data = json_decode($url,true);
$file="file.txt"; 
foreach ($data['response'] as $item) {

    $link = $item['attachment']['photo']['src_big'];
    $exists = false;

    foreach (getLines($file) as $line) {
        $exists = $exists || trim($line) === $link;
    }

    if (!$exists) {
        file_put_contents ($file, $link . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
```

Comment: Все точь в точь как вы написали, а не работает :( PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$line' (T_VARIABLE) . in line 41 ( а именно while ($line = fgets($f))).

Comment: @ВладимирВ. Подправил свой код. Запустил, работает. Убедитесь, что файл существует! У меня не хватало `;`, но совсем в другой строке. Проверьте свой код или добавьте в вопрос я могу глянуть.

Comment: @ВладимирВ. Вы наверное строкой выше пропустили `;` или что то похожее.

Comment: @ВладимирВ. Попробуйте полностью скопировать и запустить. А потом редактируйте.

Запустить без сервера можно с командной строки. `php file.php`.  PS: Пробовал под 5.6

Comment: у меня тоже 5.6 Добавил свой код в вопрос

Comment: @ВладимирВ. Обновил. поменял ваш `for` на `foreach` . Если не сработает можете поменять обратно.

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает. Я с php мало знаком, но это пока.

Comment: @ВладимирВ. Да не зачто, все мы учимся. В теории можно еще больше код ускорить(усложнить), что бы не открывать файл кажды раз. Но это уже сами смотрите. http://php.net/manual/en/class.generator.php, http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Comment: @ВладимирВ. Если всё правильно, примите ответ как правильный.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
//Тут в переменную записываем вашу ссылку (в цикле, которым парсится все)
$str="http://link.ru";  
//Открываем ваш файл с ссылками
$file=file("link.txt"); 
//Проверяем наличие $str в $file
if(!in_array($str,$file)){ 
 //если нет такой,пишите в файл строку, тем способом каким и записывали ранее, если есть - ничего не происходит 
}

?>
```

Comment: Ответ правильный но если позволяет версия PHP то надо использовать генераторы. Они и быстрее будут и память не используют.

Comment: Само собой, но на сколько мне известно не все  хостинги работают с PHP начиная с версии 5.5 (поддержкой генераторов)

Comment: PHP 5.5 На сегодня уже даже не обновляеться и не поддеживаеться, надо бежать с того хостинга который не обновился.